# Constrained QP problem with C++ CasADi library apparently does not take into account the costraint function

Tags: c++, optimization, casadi

I don't know if someone can help here as the target community may not be so wide, but I will give it a try.

I'm practicing with the open-source C++ [CasADi](https://web.casadi.org/) library for optimization and I'm struggling with the implementation of a quadratic programming (QP) problem with a linear constraint. Unfortunately, the official documentation regarding the proper syntax for C++ is only partial and deducing it from the other languages (Python, MATLAB) is not always that easy.

To make it short, inspired also by the example programs of the library, I wrote a minimal replicable code for a trivial QP problem such as:

```
casadi::SX xs = casadi::SX::sym("xs");
casadi::SX ys = casadi::SX::sym("ys");
casadi::SX fs = (xs) * (xs) + (ys) * (ys);
casadi::SX gs = xs - 3.0;
casadi::SXDict qp_problem = { {"x",casadi::SX::vertcat({xs,ys})}, {"f", fs}, {"g",gs}};
casadi::Function qp_solution = casadi::qpsol("QPproblem", "qrqp", qp_problem);
std::vector<double> x0 = { 10,10 };
casadi::DMDict arg = { {"x0",x0} };

std::cout << "Extracting the solution ... " << std::endl;
casadi::DMDict res = qp_solution(arg);

std::cout << "res[x] = " << res["x"] << std::endl;
```

According to the official [documentation](https://web.casadi.org/docs/#quadratic-programming), the variable `gs` specifies a linear inequality constraint as `xs - 3.0 >= 0`, while `fs` is the cost function to minimize.
As such, I would expect that the resulting minimum value for the `x` (i.e., `res[x]`) was `(3,0)` in virtue of the constraint. Instead, the output of the above-reported code returns the pair `(0,0)`, i.e., as if the constraint function `gs` was not taken into account. I've also tried in changing the vertex of the paraboloid in `fs` (i.e., by testing `fs = (xs-x0) * (xs-x0) + (ys-y0) * (ys-y0)`), obtaining always the pair `(x0,y0)` as minimum, independently on the expression of the constraint `gs`.

Is there anything in the syntax that I'm possibly writing wrongly, or something in the discussion that I'm uncorrectly considering?

Thanks in advance for any help